# $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \lvert f(x)\rvert = \lvert\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)\rvert$?

Tags: limits, examples-counterexamples, absolute-value

Are we always allowed to assume that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \lvert f(x)\rvert = \lvert\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)\rvert$?

I don't think so, but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: It is indeed continuous in this case.

Comment: @Julian not sure what you mean by in this case, $|x|$ is continuous for all real numbers $x$

Comment: $|\cdot|$ is always continuous :)

Comment: No, I mean that $f(x)$ is continuous by premise. Isn't this what Gibbs meant?

Comment: @Julian I am sorry, I was not clear. You are allowed as long as $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ is continuous and the limits exist. You do not need the continuity of $f$. That would actually imply $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(\lim_{x \to a} x)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\geqslant 0\\-1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $\lim_{x\to0}\bigl|f(x)\bigr|=1$, whereas $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ doesn't exist.